# How to create xml for API instead of manual if conditions for each element in model?

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I have a laravel project with dynamic forms (created from db) and for each of this forms I need to create an XML for API with different style.
How can I create them automatically or from an template? I mean I could create them manually but this would blow the model up with hundred of code lines e.g.

```
if($myvar['xyz'] == "foo")
   $xml .= "<SOMENODE>$myvar['xyz']</SOMENODE>";
}
```

But some of the elements also have child elements...
Is there an more elegant way?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I created a Laravel package to simplify XML responses for APIs: https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml

With the package it's as easy as setting up an array or collection to specify the format you want. Here's a simple example using the package:

```
$products = Product::all();
$array = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'data' => $products
];

return response()->xml($array);
```

That's a very simple example. If you need a more complete response transformer setup, I recommend you use [Spatie's Laravel Fractal package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal) with my own. It will help you format the data in exactly the way you want and you'll get perfectly valid xml.

This should give you everything you need to get going.